# same QML SoundEffect's .wav file is heard differently under Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, qt, audio

In my Qt/QML project, I have sound file `UeUserLogonFailed.wav` and it is declared as

```
SoundEffect
{
    id: ueUserLoginFailedSound

    source: "qrc:///ueSounds/sounds/UeUserLogonFailed.wav"

    volume: 0.3
}   // SoundEffect
```

Now, when I run this app under **Windows OS**, I hear nice sound once user makes login error (i.e., enters wrong credentials). However, in **Linux**, particulary in `KUbuntu 15.10`, which is used as development machine, I repeat same procedure on purpose (user logon failed) and I get heavily distorted sound from speakers. Why?
P.S.: I use `Qt 5.5.1 64bit` on `KUbuntu 15.10`.

Comment: the file sounds correctly when played via a regular mediaplayer?

Comment: using `VLC media player`, yes.

Comment: @FrancisStraccia do you think I should convert it to some more "platform-independent" format, like `flac` or even `mp3`?

Comment: no, I thought it could be the audio subsystem of the OS (PulseAudio to be precise) to create the distortion. Converting to mp3 could be worth the time though

Comment: @FrancisStraccia I've converted it, changed qrc location to point to `.mp3` version of file and now I get error:`QSoundEffect(pulseaudio): Error decoding source`

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QSoundEffect.html - it seems QSoundEffect can't handle mp3s

Comment: @FrancisStraccia yes, I've checked. do you think my issue is a Qt bug?

Comment: you should try creating a sample application using regular Qt (not QML) and its regular audio playback facilities (QSoundEffect, QMediaPlayer, etc.) and see if the problem is always present.